# WSO2 app managemt UI empty

Tags: wso2-iot

When I go to 'App Management' tab in the Emm, I get an empty page. 
In Chrome debug console I see: "GET https://81.218.41.99:9443/favicon.ico 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Because just the image shouldn't render the whole page as empty.

Comment: Hi, It was solved by modifiying the host file under sytem32\drivers\etc

Comment: Can you please close the question if it still open?

Comment: How do I close a question?..

Comment: Go through the meta link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Comment: Tried to answer my own question but my answer was refused..  This is a very annoying process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Solved by editing the host file under windows/system32/etc/drivers.